# Remove the null line in a text file

Tags: c#

I like to export a text file to be read by some PLC which could not process empty or null lines. The \r\n in WriteLine generate a null line at the end of the text file, and I could not figure a way to not generate it or to remove it.

This is how I generate and write the lines:

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
lines.Add(...);
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    file.WriteLine(line);
}
```

I tried removing the line with the following code but the end null line remains:

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).Where(arg => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arg)).ToList();
File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
```

I also tried deleting the last line, but of course it remove the last line instead of the carriage return..

```
lines = lines.GetRange(0, lines.Count - 1);
```

The image demonstrate pictorially the issue (left) and what I like to achieve (right)

[image]

Comment: Write the last `line` with `.Write()`. Use a for loop rather than a `foreach`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not generating the blank line at the first place will solve your problem, since you are calling `WriteLine` each time, it adds `\r\n` to the end of each line, including the last one. You can use a `for` loop instead and check if you are writing the last line, call `Write` method instead of `WriteLine`:

```
for(int i=0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    if(i == lines.Length - 1)
    {
        file.Write(line);
    }
    else 
    {
        file.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you use `WriteLine`, it adds end-of-line to the end

What you need it to avoid last end-of-line, by using `Write` instead of `WriteLine`

For example:

```
file.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your sollution:

```
  var lst = new List<string> { "jkl", "rueioqwp", "JKL:", "reqwdasf" };

   for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
       {
            string newLine = "";
            if (i != lst.Count - 1)
                newLine = Environment.NewLine;
            File.AppendAllText("c:\\temp\\tmp.txt", lst[i] + newLine);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to remove lines that only contain whitespace, use

---

### resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"^\s+$[\r\n]*", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);

^\s+$ will remove everything from the first blank line to the last (in a contiguous block of empty lines), including lines that only contain tabs or spaces.

[\r\n]* will then remove the last CRLF (or just LF which is important because the .NET regex engine matches the $ between a \r and a \n, funnily enough)

Comment: It probably best to just avoid writing the last line rather than putting another layer of work on top to remove it.